# How to wait for Retrofit call function to end completely before running next function?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose

In my jetpack compose app I'm retrieving data from API with retrofit. The problem is that the **viewModel.updateFlightSearch** function is being run just after the getLocation function, and the **viewModel.location.value** is null, because Retrofit  call haven't finished yet. How can i wait with running the **updateFlightSearch** function until the Retrofit call is fully finished, and **viewModel.location.value** variable is updated?

```
fun getLocation(name: String) =
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _loading.value = true
            val response = repository.getLocation(name)

            when (response) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    _location.value = response.data!!.first()
                    _loading.value = false
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    _loading.value = true
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    _error.value = response.message.toString()
                    Log.d("ErrorLocation", _error.value)
                    _loading.value = false
                }
            }
        }
```

Then I want to update the data for FlightSearch with a function:

```
fun updateFlightSearch(
        cityDep: String = "", cityArr: String = "", date: String = "", pass: Int = 0
    ) {
        if (cityDep != "")
            _flightSearch.value.locationDeparture = cityDep
        if (cityArr != "")
            _flightSearch.value.locationArrival = cityArr
        if (date != "")
            _flightSearch.value.departureTime = date
        if (pass != 0)
            _flightSearch.value.passengers = pass
    }
```

I'm running both function after certain button is being clicked:

```
MyDialog(
                openDialog = viewModel.isDialogOpen,
                param = viewModel.selectedButtonName.value,
                
                ) { city ->
                when (viewModel.selectedButtonIndex.value) {
                    0 -> {
                        viewModel.getLocation(city)
                        viewModel.updateFlightSearch(viewModel.location.value.cityCode.toString())

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are calling the "updateFlightSearch" function outside of your coroutine.
By doing this the first "getLocation" function will run in a separate thread and "updateFlightSearch" will run next in the main thread.
What I would do is call "updateFlightSearch inside the coroutine, when the call to "repository.getLocation" succeeds.

```
fun getLocation(name: String) =
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        _loading.value = true
        val response = repository.getLocation(name)

        when (response) {
            is Resource.Success -> {
                _location.value = response.data!!.first()
                _loading.value = false
                viewModel.updateFlightSearch(response.data!!.first()value.cityCode.toString())

            }
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                _loading.value = true
            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                _error.value = response.message.toString()
                Log.d("ErrorLocation", _error.value)
                _loading.value = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I get your point. The problem with this solution is that I want to use updateFlightSearch method further in my application, without executing the getLocation method.

Comment: Well, in that case, what I would do is use an observer and, for example, when the "getLocation" method sends "success" to what I am observing, it performs the "updateFlightSearch" method and in case of another message it would show a pop-up or a toast of error.

Comment: Is it possible to write something like that using my Resource wrapper class and _loading?